# How do I differentiate a product $a(x) b(x) c(x)$ of three functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, products

If I have a function $$f(x)=a(x)\cdot b(x)\cdot c(x),$$ where I cannot simplify any further, how do I differentiate it?

For example, how would I differentiate $$f(x)=(x^2+5x+6)\cdot(e^{2x})\cdot(\cos(\pi+x))\ ?$$

Comment: Use the product rule and use it again.

Comment: Make $a(x)b(x)$ the first function.

Comment: Hint: $[a\cdot b \cdot c]'=\left[\frac{a\cdot b}{c^{-1}}\right]'$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint** Given the three (differentiable) functions $a, b, c$, we can suggestively rewrite their product as $$abc = (ab)c .$$ Then, applying the product rule to the factor functions $ab$ and $c$ gives
$$(abc)' = [(ab) c]' = (ab)' c + ab c' ,$$
which reduces the computation to determining the derivative $(ab)'$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ and their derivatives, but this is exactly the content of the usual product rule that you already know.

Answer (score 7):

A classic trick is by using implicit differentiation:

Given that

$$\log f(x) = \log(x^2+5x+6)+2x+\log(\cos(x+\pi))$$

we differentiate wrt $x$ to get

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{2x+5}{x^2+5x+6}+2+\frac{-\sin(x+\pi)}{\cos(x+\pi)}$$

That is,

$$f'(x) = f(x)\left(\frac{2x+5}{x^2+5x+6}+2+\frac{-\sin(x+\pi)}{\cos(x+\pi)}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: we have $$f'(x)=a'(x)b(x)c(x)+a(x)b'(x)c(x)+a(x)b(x)c'(x)$$ for your example we get $$f'(x)=(2x+5)\exp(2x)\cos(\pi+x)+(x^2+5x+6)\exp(2x)2\cos(\pi+x)+(x^2+5x+6)\exp(2x)\cdot (-\sin(x+\pi))$$

Comment: This hint is not too useful, since it doesn't give a clue on how you get this formula.

Comment: The *formula* is useful, though. It generalizes to any number of factors, too (including 0 or 1). For example, if $f(x) = a(x) b(x) c(x) d(x)$, then $f'(x) = a'(x) b(x) c(x) d(x) + a(x) b'(x) c(x) d(x) + a(x) b(x) c'(x) d(x) + a(x) b(x) c(x) d'(x)$.